# How to export Entity-Relation created in Confluence plugin draw.io to SQL?

Tags: draw.io

I am using draw.io plugin (macro) in confluence. There is set of shapes related to Entity Relation. Using those shapes we have created DB design. It is very handy and good to manipulate. However now I want to export this design in SQL scripts so that I do not need to create them manually. However I couldn't find a way to do that.

On other thread I find that there is a feature to create diagram from SQL under "Menu" -> "Arrange" -> "Insert" -> "Advanced" -> "SQL". There is no way to do the reverse of it.

Is there any other way to do that? The only option is see is to do it manually and stop using darw.io in future.

Please help.